# Need to update UITableViewCell data real time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm

Im working on bluetooth application getting device data from broadcasting devices, all data coming with out any issue, this code we use to test our devices and this code base filtering only those devices

let deviceLocations: [String: String] = [
"00000534": "Office room",
"00000523": "Reception",
"00000525": "Lunch room"
]

I added for that purpose
All working with out any any issue

I have tableview its showing Device Name, UUID, RSSI and the Location

My question is Im getting realtime values from the devices but that values not updating in the table view cell.

need to update table view data in real time

need to mention I added refresher for 5 seconds but still not working

I have tachhed my code bellow. anyone please help me to fix this issue

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import Combine

class DeviceListViewController: UIViewController, BluetoothManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var strongestRSSILabel: UILabel!
    
    var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager!
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var discoveredDevices: [CBPeripheral] = []
    var rssiValues: [CBPeripheral: NSNumber] = [:]
    var rssiValue: Int = 0
    var rssiUpdateTimer: Timer?
    var deviceInfoArray: [DeviceInfo] = []
    
    @Published var strongestRSSI: NSNumber?
    var strongestPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    
    let deviceLocations: [String: String] = [
        "00000534": "Office room",
        "00000523": "Reception",
        "00000525": "Lunch room"
    ]
    
    private var observation: AnyCancellable?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        
        bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
        bluetoothManager.delegate = self
        bluetoothManager.startScanning()
        
        observation = $strongestRSSI
            .sink { [weak self] newValue in
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        
        refreshTableView()
        
        rssiUpdateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(refreshTableView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(rssiUpdateTimer!, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            // Start scanning for peripheral devices with RSSI values
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        // Update the RSSI value whenever a peripheral is discovered
        rssiValue = RSSI.intValue
        
        // You may want to update your data source here as well
    }
    
    @objc func refreshTableView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.filterDiscoveredDevices()
            self.filterDiscoveredDevicesRSSI()
            
            // Check if strongestRSSI has changed and the strongestPeripheral is available
            if let strongestRSSI = self.strongestRSSI,
               let strongestPeripheral = self.strongestPeripheral,
               let indexPath = self.indexPathForPeripheral(strongestPeripheral) {
                let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DeviceTableViewCell
                cell?.rssiLabel?.text = "RSSI: \(strongestRSSI)"
            }
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("Table view refreshed ======================================== HHHH")
        }
    }
    
    // Function to find the IndexPath for a given peripheral
    private func indexPathForPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) -> IndexPath? {
        for (index, device) in discoveredDevices.enumerated() {
            if device === peripheral {
                return IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func filterDiscoveredDevices() {
        discoveredDevices = discoveredDevices.filter { peripheral in
            if let name = peripheral.name {
                return ["00000534", "00000523", "00000525"].contains(name)
            }
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func filterDiscoveredDevicesRSSI() {
        // Filter the discovered devices based on the names
        let filteredDevices = discoveredDevices.filter { peripheral in
            if let name = peripheral.name {
                return ["00000534", "00000523", "00000525"].contains(name)
            }
            return false
        }
        
        // Fetch RSSI values for the filtered devices
        for peripheral in filteredDevices {
            peripheral.readRSSI()
        }
        
        // Determine the strongest RSSI value among the filtered devices
        var strongestRSSI: NSNumber?
        var strongestLocation: String?
        
        for peripheral in filteredDevices {
            if let rssi = rssiValues[peripheral] {
                if strongestRSSI == nil || rssi.intValue > strongestRSSI!.intValue {
                    strongestRSSI = rssi
                    strongestLocation = deviceLocations[peripheral.name ?? ""]
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Update strongestRSSI using @Published
        self.strongestRSSI = strongestRSSI
        
        // Update the UILabel with the combined label
        var combinedLabelText = "Strongest RSSI: N/A"
        if let strongestRSSI = strongestRSSI, let strongestLocation = strongestLocation {
            combinedLabelText = "Strongest RSSI: \(strongestRSSI), Location: \(strongestLocation)"
        }
        
        strongestRSSILabel.text = combinedLabelText
    }
    
    // Implement BluetoothManagerDelegate methods
    func bluetoothManager(_ manager: BluetoothManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, withRSSI RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if !discoveredDevices.contains(peripheral) {
            rssiValues[peripheral] = RSSI
            discoveredDevices.append(peripheral)
            filterDiscoveredDevices()
            filterDiscoveredDevicesRSSI()
            tableView.reloadData()
            
            // Check if the RSSI is stronger than the current strongest RSSI
            if strongestRSSI == nil || RSSI.intValue > strongestRSSI!.intValue {
                strongestRSSI = RSSI
                strongestPeripheral = peripheral
            }
        }
    }

    
    func refreshRSSIValues() {
        for peripheral in discoveredDevices {
            peripheral.readRSSI()
        }
    }
    
    func bluetoothManager(_ manager: BluetoothManager, didStartAdvertisingPeripheral success: Bool) {
        if success {
            // Start advertising
        } else {
            // Handle advertising failure
        }
    }
    
    // Implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return discoveredDevices.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DeviceCell", for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell
        
        let peripheral = discoveredDevices[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel?.text = "Device Name: \(peripheral.name ?? "Unnamed Device")"
        cell.uuidLabel?.text = "UUID: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)"
        
        // Get the RSSI value from the dictionary
        if let rssi = rssiValues[peripheral] {
            cell.rssiLabel?.text = "RSSI: \(rssi)"
        } else {
            cell.rssiLabel?.text = "RSSI: N/A"
        }
        
        if let location = deviceLocations[peripheral.name ?? "Device Name"] {
            cell.locationLabel?.text = "Location: \(location)"
        } else {
            cell.locationLabel?.text = "Location: N/A"
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: please print "discoveredDevices" in numberOfRowsInSection and check it.

Comment: That's quite a bit of code but I think the approach is the issue. Assuming the data is stored in Realm (per the tag), and that data is loaded as a results, which is turn is the datasource for the tableview, you would add an observer to the Realm results and as that data changes (add, modify or remove) the observer will receive an event and then reload your tableview to display the changes. e.g. let the controller (MVC pattern) update the view as the data changes).